# who will call message_function in dbus.

Tags: dbus

When we register DBusObjectPathVTable then who will call the message_function? i.e dbus-daemon will call or the dbus main loop ( _dbus_loop_run function) will call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libdbus will call members of the `DBusObjectPathVTable` from the libdbus main loop. You could have checked this yourself by grepping for the members in the libdbus source code: `cd dbus.git && git grep message_function` shows that `dbus/dbus-object-tree.c` contains all the calls to it. `dbus-object-tree.c` is part of libdbus.

It is highly recommended that you use a D-Bus library *other* than libdbus, however, as libdbus is fiddly to use correctly. If possible, use [GDBus](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) or [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) instead, as they are much higher-level bindings which are easier to use. If you need a lower-level binding, [sd-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) is more modern than libdbus.